# GLEW fails to work in Visual Studios 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opengl, glew

My multi-project solution closes down when I try to run it with glewInit(). The project builds fine on its own though. When I comment out this one line, the solution can run.

I am writing a project that is part of a large solution in Visual Studios 2010. The project uses a 3rd party graphics library called coin3d. I have downloaded and installed/included glew, and there are no linking issues with that because the project will build fine without any errors. This project has no entry point, the dll it produces is just used by the solution. So I cannot view any specific runtime error logs about it. It only tells me it cannot find the dll of the project when it fails.

I know that the 3rd party graphics library creates the opengl context, because I am able use regular opengl to render some geometry and whatnot to the screen. But as soon as I run glewInit(), the project fails to run (even though it builds). Is there a way to check and print whether or not the context was created? (Just to be sure)

On the website for GLEW it says:

```
"On Windows, you also need to define the GLEW_STATIC preprocessor token when
 building a static library or executable, and the GLEW_BUILD preprocessor
 token when building a dll"
```

does that mean just put them into the project's preprocessor definitions like this?
[image: preprocessor definition]

I tried getting it to run with just GLEW_BUILD, and not GLEW_STATIC. It didn't make a difference. Are there any steps I'm missing?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Are you unable to build GLEW? Did you build GLEW but are unable to *use* it successfully? You show screenshots of a project; is that the GLEW project itself, or a project that you want to *use* GLEW?

Comment: Make sure glew.h is included BEFORE gl.h or any other OpenGL headers.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think I am able to build glew fine. When I build the project there are no errors. That is how to build glew? When I run the project with the line "glewInit()" it doesn't work. The screenshot is of the project that I want to directly use GLEW.

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar Yes I have made sure that I include Glew before other openl. In fact, I only include the glew header--it accounts for the gl header as well.

Comment: You made sure to add glew32.lib to your linker inputs right? If not, right click on your project, click Properties, then go to Linker->Input and prepend glew32.lib to the Additional Depedencies list.

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar Yes I've made sure that glew32.lib, OpenGL32.lib, and GlU32.lib are in my inputs of the project. There are no linker issues when I build the project. As far as I can tell it's a problem with building the dll when the whole solution needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to check and print whether or not the context was created? (Just to be sure)

You can do the following:

```
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}
```